# How can you forward delete all in macOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

If you type a sentence and hold <kbd>command</kbd> then press <kbd>delete</kbd> then it'll delete the whole line. What if I want to insert the cursor in the middle of a sentence and forward delete the right of the sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within default macOS apps (e.g. TextEdit) as well as other Apple apps (e.g. Pages) you can use the <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> keyboard shortcut to delete the text between the cursor and the end of the line (or paragraph). However, this isn't supported by default in many 3rd party apps (e.g. MS Word).

However, you can use the <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd> keyboard shortcut (in standard keyboards) to delete everything to the right of the cursor up to the next space. This works in many 3rd party apps.

If you have an extended keyboard, then you don't need to use the <kbd>fn</kbd> as you have a dedicated forward delete key.

Comment: That only forward deletes the word to the right of the cursor

Comment: That's right, the second keyboard shortcut only deletes everything to the right of the cursor *up to the next space*. The first keyboard shortcut is what you're really after, but it only works in Apple apps. I'm not sure how many 3rd party apps support the same shortcut. Were you wanting this for a particular app?

Comment: I use "Fn" "Delete" on my MacBook Pro to do that, but the problem here is that Mac external keyboards (that I have seen) don't usually have one of those "Fn" keys. But if you plug in a PC keyboard the "Delete" key (over the arrow keys) will do this.